# Check constraint to avoid spaces on string

Tags: sql-server

Is there an easy way to avoid entering spaces on one column?

For example I have a column Code and I need to enter values without any space:

`'CFDA'` -> is good

`'CF DA'` -> is not good

Comment: `WHERE c NOT LIKE '% %'`

Comment: perfect, it works! thanks

Comment: `charindex(' ',c)=0` would work as well.

Comment: My gut feeling is that `charindex` will be more performant than `like`.

Comment: @ajeh Dont list to your guts, just test it  to see which is better ;)

Comment: i guess i understood differently, I would think he needed a REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )  instead. e.g. `REPLACE(@MyString, ' ', '')`

Comment: @RicardoC Using `REPLACE` in a `CHECK` constraint (e.g. `CHECK REPLACE( col, ' ', '' ) = col`) would be very inefficient because it means having to do a string allocation for every time the `CHECK` contraint is evaluated, whereas a _read-only_ operation using simple scalars, like `CHARINDEX` or `LIKE` is considerably cheaper.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a user defined column constraint directly when creating the table. E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    -- other columns
    Code NVARCHAR(64) CONSTRAINT CK_MyTable_Code_NoSpace CHECK (CHARINDEX(' ',Code ) < 1),
    -- other columns
)
```

This ensures that any `INSERT`/`UPDATE` in `Code` column will fail, if Code contains at least one space.